# Discrepancy between VS Code live server output and opening the index.html file by itself

Tags: html, css, image, visual-studio-code, atom-liveserver

I have a website built entirely with the css templates provided by w3.css.
I have multiple style sheets with the direct link to the online css files provided by w3.css and I do NOT have a css folder. I have an images folder with all my images.

**Currently, when I load the website using VS Code's live preview plugin, the website displays perfectly, but when I open the index.html file manually, there seems to be an issue with the images / css. Why is this happening?**

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"
```

This a short line from my styles section.

```
img src="/img/header.jpg" alt="Lombok Beach" width="1600px" height="750px"
```

And this is one of the many image tags where the images are not showing.

Comment: On one of the urls you might have cached some files. Try pressing CTRL+F5 on both and see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: @MauriceNino I wasnt really sure what you meant, but I definitely tried to refresh all the links to my css files and retyped all my img tags. It didn't work, but when I tried to relink the images using dreamweaver, it works. Still no idea what was the problem, but thanks anyway! (:

Comment: Thats weird. Glad you could solve it anyways! :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer and it worked well for me.
You should use 'relative' file paths instead of 'absolute' file paths.
It means you shouldn't write a "/" (absolute path) in the first of direction. Start with a './' or nothing (relative).
e.g: "img/header.jpg"
On a live server environment, a '/' points to your root website dir.
Watch this for more information:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMT3JUWmqYY

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32690473)