# Contents on .html page and vscode live-server page appears differently

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I am using html and css to create a website for my school project. 
I was writing my script by using vscode and everything was fine on the live-server page. 
[Live Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zo8O.jpg)
However, when I ran the actual .html file through my browser, it appeared differently from my live-server page. 
[.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3GjS.png)

I think some wrong with {background-image: url("/images/banner.jpeg");} this tag but I'm not sure. Please help!

```
<div class="banner"></div>


.banner {
   background-image: url("/images/banner.jpeg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   padding: 200px 1px;
   min-height: 20%;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a relative and not absolute file path: `background-image: url("images/banner.jpeg");`

More info: [Discrepancy between VS Code live server output and opening the index.html file by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55630470/discrepancy-between-vs-code-live-server-output-and-opening-the-index-html-file-b/73675044#73675044)